# Relay turn on by any of 3 touch sensors

Tags: arduino, touch, sensors, android-sensors, relay

I have a relay and i want to turn on the light with it and i have 2 touch sensors but with this code i can only turn it on with 1 how can i make it work? The third is a switch but it should still work the same. I've tried and it worked with a different code. But that code was for a servo and not a relay.

```
int touchPin   = 4;
int touchPin2   = 6;   // Arduino pin connected to touch sensor's pin
int touchPin3   = 7 ;
int relayPin = 9;

int val = 0;
int lightON = 0;
int touched = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(touchPin, INPUT); 
    pinMode(touchPin2, INPUT);
      pinMode(touchPin3, INPUT);
  pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {

  val = digitalRead(touchPin);
    val = digitalRead(touchPin2);
      val = digitalRead(touchPin3);

  if(val == HIGH && lightON == LOW){

    touched = 1-touched;
    delay(100);
  }    

  lightON = val;

      if(touched == HIGH){
        Serial.println("Light ON");
        digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW); 
       
      }else{
        Serial.println("Light OFF");
        digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);
   
      }     

  delay(100);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle all three digital inputs together. In your code

```
val = digitalRead(touchPin);
val = digitalRead(touchPin2);
val = digitalRead(touchPin3);
```

you are overwriting the first two read values by the last one. You should combine them or handle all three separately. Combining three reads to one value that will be HIGH if **any** is HIGH:

```
val = digitalRead(touchPin) || digitalRead(touchPin2) || digitalRead(touchPin3);
```

Separately:

```
int val  = digitalRead(touchPin);
int val2 = digitalRead(touchPin2);
int val3 = digitalRead(touchPin3);

if ((val == HIGH || val2 == HIGH || val3 == HIGH) && lightON == LOW) {
```

Comment: Tried both of them the first one just started turning on and off and the second one the separate just stays on

Comment: Tnx this worked one of my pins was on for some reason and it registerd as on thats why it was turning on and off